# How to add featured_image field on all existing posts containing the image

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

I have over a thousands posts, each of them contains a featured image.
For some reasons I need to create a featured_image custom field containing the featured image url.

Is it possible to make it now, or maybe the only way was creating it before the posts?

Comment: Why do you need a custom field for featured image? Cant you use the default one?

Comment: Because the normal code for calling featured image url is very long, while i need to setup <meta property="og:image" content=""/> with it... so the only way is to take the img url from custom field

Answer (score 0):

you can set the custom field for that post type and then you can update the meta field for all posts using loop and set the feature image. Like below

```
$loop = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'Property',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
  )
);
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

    $imageurl = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(),'full');
    update_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'custom_featured_image', $imageurl  );

endwhile; wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: So in summary I just have to create a custom field name dedicated to that purpose, then just add the above code to functions.php file and it will run the transformation just after without needing to launch any command?

Comment: you will need to replace the key in the update_post_meta and post type value in the WP query then it will work

Comment: can you kindly tell me how to do this as well? sorry im not very used to these codes, im a newbie :)